# What is the alternative option in KVM similar to "Linked Clone" in VirtualBox?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, kvm

I am new to KVM, I was using VirtualBox for managing my VMs.
I see there is a clone option available in KVM but it is taking more time to clone the VM with compare to VirtualBox. 
May I know are there any alternative option available in KVM?

Comment: How are you cloning a VM?

Comment: @MichaelHampton In KVM -> Open Virtual Machine Manager -> Right click a VM -> Clone  -> and then clone.  It will take about 2 to 3 mins to complete the clone. On the other hand, in Virtual Box -> right click the VM -> Clone -> Linked Clone -> Next , next. It just takes a sec to clone the VM.

Comment: Virtualbox "linked clone" just takes the content of an existing virtual disk as a base and applies new writes in a separate image.  KVM clone from the GUI will just make a full copy of the virtual disk so each machine has its own copy.  If you are using QCOW2 in KVM, it should have the capability to replicate virtualbox "linked clone" behavior, have you tried [this](https://superuser.com/questions/958739/create-linked-clone-or-layered-shared-disks-with-qemu)?

Comment: @GracefulRestart that just works pretty! Thanks for the link. Still, it's not that easy as VirtualBox. I have to manually add the disk to Virtual Machine Manager after creating the image. Anyway, it's the function that I want in KVM. Thanks.